# Unique permutations of a list without repetition

Tags: python

I understand there are many, *many* posts about [permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592299/generating-unique-permutations-in-python) ([unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23711113/generating-unique-permutations), [variable length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698029/unique-permutations-of-variable-length), [etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284396/permutations-with-unique-values).), but I have not been able to use them to solve my particular issue.

Let's say I have a list of metropolitan areas in the United States: `['nyc','sf','atl']`

I need to output a permutation of 2 metros without repetition. For example, I've tried:

```
set(itertools.permutations(['nyc','sf','atl'], 2))

{('atl', 'nyc'),
 ('atl', 'sf'),
 ('nyc', 'atl'),
 ('nyc', 'sf'),
 ('sf', 'atl'),
 ('sf', 'nyc')}
```

However, notice that NYC and ATL are paired twice: `('nyc', 'atl')` and `('atl', 'nyc')`. The ideal output would be:

```
{('nyc', 'nyc'),
 ('nyc', 'sf'),
 ('nyc', 'atl'),
 ('sf', 'sf'),
 ('sf', 'atl'),
 ('atl', 'atl')}
```

Comment: You want combinations, `itertools.combinations`?, for example `combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD`. There is also combinations_with_replacement

Comment: @DanielMesejo yes, that will work! specifically, `list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(['nyc','sf','atl'], 2))` is exactly what i am looking for because it also compares to each other (e.g., i get `('nyc', 'nyc')` in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Daniel Mesejo comment, use combinations.

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> set(itertools.combinations(['nyc','sf','atl'], 2))
{('nyc', 'atl'), ('sf', 'atl'), ('nyc', 'sf')}
```

Comment: Why do you use `permutations` then?

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo